# Get all windows in taskbar

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

ive been googling for hours but cant find any way to get all windows in the taskbar.
I need to minimize/maximize all windows, but with enumthreadwindows all system process-thread windows are being maximized/restored and my pc crashes because of 1000 windows trying to maximize/restore...

can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

The windows displayed in taskbar are equivalent to those that appear when you press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>  So you can check these links.

[Enumerate windows like alt-tab does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210504/enumerate-windows-like-alt-tab-does)

[Which windows appear in the Alt+Tab list?](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/08/5351207.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you should try using `EnumDesktopWindows()` ([documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682615%28VS.85%29.aspx)). it will restrain the enumeration to top level windows which are part of the desktop.

Answer (score -1):

[IShellDispatch4.ToggleDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774124(VS.85).aspx) minimize/maximize all desktop windows