# Get list of windows in taskbar on Windows 7?

Tags: c++, c, windows-7, windows

how can I get a list of windows shown on the taskbar on Windows 7? I have tried EnumWindows, but I'm getting way more windows than those shown on the taskbar (800 vs 15).

Comment: I'm trying to display all windows in the taskbar on the screen at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a similar problem to [Enumerate windows like alt-tab does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210504/enumerate-windows-like-alt-tab-does)

That points to a [Raymond Chen blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/08/5351207.aspx) about getting the same windows that Alt-Tab reports.  Not sure if that's exactly the same as what's on the Win7 taskbar, but it should be close.