# windows executables corresponding to system tray icons?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

Is there a way to use Python to get a list of all the icons in the system tray (lower right hand corner) and their associated processes and executables?

Here is a thread on how to do this using AHK:

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic17314.html

but it relies heavily on AHK.

Note that I'm interested this for in Windows XP/7

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is thick, thick win32 stuff. I started writing this using pywin32 but switched over to ctypes to better deal with the structures.  Note, I wrote this in 32 win XP. You'll have the change the TBBUTTON [def](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for 64 bit.  I am not sure what UAC will do to this (can you allocate memory in another process?).

```
import commctrl, win32con
from ctypes import *

# represent the TBBUTTON structure
# note this is 32 bit, 64 bit padds 4 more reserved bytes
class TBBUTTON(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('iBitmap', c_int),
        ('idCommand', c_int),
        ('fsState', c_ubyte),
        ('fsStyle', c_ubyte),
        ('bReserved', c_ubyte * 2),
        ('dwData', c_ulong),
        ('iString', c_int),
    ]

# get the handle to the sytem tray
hWnd = windll.user32.FindWindowA("Shell_TrayWnd", None)
hWnd = windll.user32.FindWindowExA(hWnd, None, "TrayNotifyWnd", None)
hWnd = windll.user32.FindWindowExA(hWnd, None, "SysPager", None)
hWnd = windll.user32.FindWindowExA(hWnd, None, "ToolbarWindow32", None)

# get the count of icons in the tray
numIcons = windll.user32.SendMessageA(hWnd, commctrl.TB_BUTTONCOUNT, 0, 0)

# allocate memory within the system tray
pid = c_ulong();
windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, byref(pid))
hProcess = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid)
lpPointer = windll.kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, 0, sizeof(TBBUTTON), win32con.MEM_COMMIT, win32con.PAGE_READWRITE)

# init our tool bar button and a handle to it
tbButton = TBBUTTON()
butHandle = c_int()

for i in range(numIcons):
    # query the button into the memory we allocated
    windll.user32.SendMessageA(hWnd, commctrl.TB_GETBUTTON, i, lpPointer)
    # read the memory into our button struct
    windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpPointer, addressof(tbButton), 20, None)
    # read the 1st 4 bytes from the dwData into the butHandle var
    # these first 4 bytes contain the handle to the button
    windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, tbButton.dwData, addressof(butHandle), 4, None)

    # get the pid that created the button
    butPid = c_ulong()
    windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(butHandle, byref(butPid))

    # i leave it to you to get the process from the pid
    # that should be trivial...
    print butPid
```

Comment: BTW, how would I get access to the running applications taskbar. Namely, the icons that show what foreground applications are running. These are not in the system tray.

Comment: @reckoner, essentially you want what is in alt+tab?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210504/enumerate-windows-like-alt-tab-does

Comment: thanks for the link. That gets me part of the way there. My case is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like it relies more on windows' api than on ahk, which is probably just a wrapper given that the parameters on the site you're referencing are silly for their use case-- e.g. hWnd, 101, 0,0,0,0-- which generally suggests windows' api struct-type-things  ;).  I highly doubt you can just plug and play anything here, given that it's a somewhat unusual goal and very specific to windows.  If you want to make your own implementation, you will most likely get a lot of help from Tim Golden's website, and if anyone's done it before, I'd imagine it was he:

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html

Mark Hammond and the core python windows' modules are also reasonable search words, but somehow there's still relatively little documentation for all of that directly, and I'd imagine the book from 2000 wouldn't be too much help now.

Otherwise, you can make any of the calls that ahk can make, but this requires reading MSDN... You're effort would be greatly reduced given that you know roughly what you want from the AHK script.  But it will still be annoying.

You might find the Grayhat Python early chapters useful if you want to see some examples of how to implement windows api calls (making the struct, calling the functions, etc).  I found that more helpful than most of the materials that come directly from the python-windows groups, which were undoubtedly just a bit over my head.

Best of luck

Comment: thanks for the references. I will look into the grayhat book. The problem with the AHK script is that it does not provide an easy way to get at the output.