# Get all windows that have taskbar icon

Tags: c#, windows, process, enums, taskbar

I am trying to get all the window handles of applications that have a taskbar icon only.

The solutions I have converted to C# that have failed:

[Enumerate windows like alt-tab does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210504/enumerate-windows-like-alt-tab-does/210519#210519)

[Enumerate windows like alt-tab does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210504/enumerate-windows-like-alt-tab-does/214213#214213)

[Enumerate windows like alt-tab does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210504/733333)

And a couple that I lost track of already.
All these solutions either crash or bring up windowless processes like svchost, plugin processes, etc.

Basically I just need the windows that are actively available in the task bar with icons.
I am using the window handle of

```
Process.MainWindowHandle
```

What are some working solutions to this?  Is there a thread with a working solution that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try retrieving all processes where the MainWindowTitle property is set.

It doesn't feel like a particularly elegant solution, but it worked for me, bringing back only those applications which were running and visibly open in the taskbar.

```
List<Process> taskBarProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().
                                         Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
                                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Doesnt work for the window explorer, any way to include those as well?

Comment: Checkout the following blog post: [Access Explorer and Internet Explorer in C# to Find Web Pages and Directories](http://omegacoder.com/?p=63). It shows how to use the [ShellWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773974(v=vs.85).aspx) object to retrieve a collection of open explorer windows.